# Change how System.Type is serialized in Serilog

Tags: c#, serilog

I using Serilog and have several log methods that log a type.  Currently when it is converted to a string the result is the full name including the namespace.  How do I change that to remove the Namespace (to shorten the log messages somewhat)?

```
Log.Information("Type is {type}", typeof(System.Int32));
//Renders as 'Type is System.Int32'.  I would prefer 'Type is Int32'.
```

Comment: `typeof(System.Int32).Name` ?

Comment: the word you were looking for is Destructuring (Serilog term for process of mapping logged values to captured values) - there's good docs on it, but the linked post is even better in your instance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

1. Custom wrapper around the original Serilog-interface
2. Simple helper

   ```
     internal static class Helper
     {
         public static string GetName(this Type type)
         {
            if (type == typeof(int))
                return "Type is Int32";

            // other cases here...

            return string.Empty;
         }
      }

    internal static class Program
    { 
        public static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Type: {typeof(int).GetName()}");
        }
    }
   ```

You can also use a hash table to lookup types with their corresponding descriptions, so you'd save all these **if..else**.

Regards

Comment: These log messages are in a lot of places, so I may have to go with Option 1.